# Access website has suddenly stopped updating particular table

Tags: asp.net

My Client website has suddenly stopped working.
7 days before it was working fine but now I am getting error
"Your URL can't be processed.Please contact system administrator"

The website is developed using Classic Asp and Microsoft Access database 2003.
Some updates functionality are working till now but some failed.

1. I have tried these approaches but getting no success.
2. -I created new database and import all data into a new database.Upload it on          server
3. -I checked there are no locks selected in the access database.
4. -I also checked database is not read-only

I haven't changed any code.I am pretty sure something wrong happened at database end.
Looking for your positive reply.

Answer (score 0):

i do not think this is a Database error as the error itself is not a DB script,

please check your web.config, it shud be smthing like this:-

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="True" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

try it and see, i had the same, i did the above nd then after no such error till now.

Comment: The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred. I got this error now

Comment: @MohitThareja   if "Send Errors To Browser" is not working set also this:

Error Pages -> 500 -> Edit Feature Settings -> "Detailed Errors" ... Also note that if the content of the error page sent back is quite short and you're using IE, IE will happily ignore the useful content sent back by the server and show you its own generic error page instead. You can turn this off in IE's options, or use a different browser.

Comment: I am using chrome browser.Is there any option in chrome browser

Comment: I have tried it on IE with uncheck show error friendly messages  but getting same error.Please help if you have any idea.